# Moving a moved draft breaks the whole topic

Tags: bug, documentation

I was trying to split a large topic into several sub-topics by moving the examples into new topics. When I was doing this, I noticed that one of the examples would be better categorized by another topic. After trying to move this draft topic, several things broke:

1. The drafts of the new topics still appear but I can't access them. I also can't delete them which means I am constantly at the 10 draft limit.
2. I can't access the original topic I tried to split-up.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having the same problem. Can't see the drafts, also can't make a new draft...