# Is the Draft Limit Appropriate?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Some [other questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330071/moving-a-moved-draft-breaks-the-whole-topic) talk about the difficulty of doing complicated cleanup of a tag. While having unlimited drafts seems problematic, having only ten open drafts across all of Documentation feels like too few - especially since drafts in the less-trafficked tags are not likely to be reviewed very quickly.

Increasing the draft limit would:

- Pro: Provide people more leeway in helping keep tags organized and clean, as they move work between topics.
- Pro: Not discourage people from committing some of their draft bandwidth to smaller topics that will take a long time to get reviewed.
- Con: Encourage people to spam drafts.

Alternatives include:

- A general draft-review queue so that reviewers are incentivized to move through the drafts that are currently put out. (This may have some downsides as well, since the more popular tags seem to be being spammed already with drafts that are not on-point.)
- Increasing draft limits based on reputation.
- Not counting the draft towards the limit in tags you have a badge in (which wouldn't help my case but might help in the general).

I'm curious what people think on this topic.

Comment: I think I've hit every single limit: 30 reviews, 50 examples, 25 topics, and, of course, 10 submitted drafts. 30 reviews happen naturally thanks to intellectually impaired users (I don't have much votes left for accepting), but all other limits are easily reached if you move topics around. **Moving one topic** with 10 examples from one tag to another results in **–20 examples, –2 topics, –2 drafts**. After moving 5 topics, I can't do anything. This is silly. (Not sure about 50 topics and 25 examples - wording of the limits is confusing.)

Comment: @Squidward I agree it's silly that moving one topic w/ 10 examples counts that way. Moving a topic (even with 10 examples) should count as 1 topic move.

Comment: *"Not counting the draft towards the limit in tags you have a badge in (which wouldn't help my case but might help in the general)."* AFAIK your changes don't need to be reviewed, if you got the silver badge in a tag (mentioned here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th?cb=1), so if you commit edits there, they won't remain drafts anyway.

Comment: @fabian Ah! Good find, if disappointing for the subset of people making good proposals and then getting locked out because they hit a limit. It does incentivize getting back to the regular question grind. :D