# Are Documentation changes rate-limited?

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation, rate-limiting

I saw a user who had suggested a lot of very minor cosmetic changes in Documentation.
Unfortunately, most of these got Approved, despite not adding any value.

We recently introduced [rate limits on edit suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/168333). Do these also apply to Documentation changes? And if so, are they limited to 5 pending suggestions (as SO is a graduated site) or to 20 (as Documentation itself is in Beta)?

The Documentation project is not mentioned in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) on MSE.
Improvement Requests [are limited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329070/documentation-why-are-improvement-requests-limited), but judging by one of the comments there, edits on Documentation are not.

If there aren't rate limits to changes on Documentation, they should be introduced. Otherwise the system encourages editing sprees for cosmetic changes.

Answer (score 8):

Someone figured out that suggestions apparently aren't rate limited:

[image]

The timing is consistent enough (across many, many accounts) to support the theory that there's a robot behind all of this. We really need some kind of sanity check here - even 2 proposals per minute would be plenty.

Comment: Unless this changed and I can't find it, there [is a draft limit of 10.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332242/is-the-draft-limit-appropriate) And unless I'm misunderstanding that post and the problems outlined there, those drafts are kept until your proposed change is reviewed. However, if these changes are rejected fast enough, it still isn't going to help much.

Comment: The user creating these changes is also constantly creating new accounts to try and get their changes in. This issue isn't just some random user who can't stop rep-whoring.

Comment: We are capped though. I hit my 30 reviews in about ten minutes rejecting all this.

Comment: Ah, I got over 20 and assumed there was no limit.

Comment: I really really hope mods will go trough this and also ban for a good while those that got approved.

Comment: @Braiam I haven't seen any get approved, please flag a post from anyone who does vote to approve one.

Comment: Just got hit with another 1600 and counting. Unable to reject with 30 review limit.