# Another round of spam in Documentation

Tags: support, documentation, spam

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/history

Somebody is currently spamming the documentation pages with chinese texts. All of them get rejected, but could please someone disable those user accounts?

Comment: Not really a dupe in my mind ... the linked post suggests how to fix it by introducing captchas, but that apparently hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: [The moderators are aware of this situation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340455/4751173), but can't do anything yet.

Comment: Ok ... I just wanted to make sure it got the necessary attention - especially as I've now reached the daily 30 review limit.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but it does.

Comment: The link is quite informative and useful right now, but I guess it won't be if somebody revisits a few hours or days from now.

Comment: @tripleee If you know how to build a link that points to the review history at this particular point in time, please feel free to edit. I didn't know any better ...

Comment: Me neither; I certainly would have provided a better link if I could.

Comment: I've seen this too: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/120188

Comment: @takrl wow, this is happening alot

Comment: @takrl I'm watching the queue and rejecting as fast as I can, hope that helps.

Comment: 7 hours into this wave, we've been hit by over 1600 spam requests. Unfortunately my rejection efforts have done nothing but exhaust my 30 review limit. At what reputation does this rate limit increase?

Comment: It seems to have stopped 12 hours ago ...